# Does CLLocationManager call the delegate with didExitRegion after device restart?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, region

I'm trying to figure out something:

When I register a region and then close my app and restart device, walking around and then restart the device outside the original region, does my app get notified?

Comment: Have you tried this scenario in your device for any other delegate other than didExitRegion? Like schedule a local notification and shutdown the device, start the device after the scheduled time, see what happen?

Comment: I've been trying to do this, but I saw a location saved to server but no notification was sent to user.